# Simulate a step at gym OpenAI

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-gym

I am trying to check how good is a step with some action at BipedalWalker-v2 environment, but even if I don't call `env.render()`, the line `_, reward, _, _ = env.step(action)` is taking too much time to run.

It seems that it is trying to make the robot really peform the step, even if it's not appearing at the screen. (I mean, render the robot at the screen takes some time, but the calculation should not take so long, right?)

Is there any way to simulate a step an check its reward?

Comment: So you want to do the step without doing the step?

Comment: I just want to know if env.step(action) really take so long to run even if no image is being presented at screen. Calling it seeing the robot taking the steps is the same that calling it without the render part? (that should take longer than the calculation itself)

Comment: That makes sense but I'm not sure your assumptions are valid. The step is itself a simulation so I don't know if you're going to be able to find a speedup here.